# If $G$ is a transitive permutation group of even degree $>2$, then 4 divides $|G|$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions

I am struggling with the following problem: If $G$ is a transitive permutation group of even degree $>2$, then  4 divides $|G|$.

What I mean by $G$ being a transitive permutation group of even degree $>2$ is that $G$ is a subgroup of the symmetric group of degree $n$, $S_n$, with $n$ being an even number greater than 2. And that $G$ acts transitively on the set $\{1,\dots, n\}$ (note that the action comes from the action of $S_n$ on $\{1,\dots,n\}$).

My first approach has been to use that for ant $x\in \{1,\dots, n\}$, the index $|G:G_x|=|\text{Orb}_G(x)|=|\{1,\dots,n\}|=n$.

Here I distinguish two cases.
If $4$ divides $n$ then $4$ divides $|G:G_x|$ and I am done.

So I can assume that $4$ does not divide $n$. We know that $2$ divides $n$, and so 2 divides $|G:G_x|$ and also $|G|$. And I have to show that two divides  $|G_x|$.

I am struggling with this. I have tried to see why $G_x$ has order divisible by 2  but I have run out of ideas.

I know that I have to use the fact that $G$ is a transitive permutation group because this is not true in general. For example, any group $G$ acts transitively over itself so you can find groups with an order divisible by $2$ and not by $4$ that act transitively over a set of even order greater than 2.

Comment: This question was asked a few days ago with degree $2$ allowed, but I cannot find it. It's still not true for larger degrees. In general there are transitive permutation groups on a set of size $n$, and they have order $n$. (By orbit-stabilizer $n$ must divide the order of a transitive permutation group.) Indeed, any group of order $n$ is transitive on itself by (left or) right multiplication, the so-called regular representation.

Comment: Please stop asking for help in proving things that are not true!

Answer (score 1):

What if $G$ is the transitive subgroup generated by the standard 6-cycle in $S_6$: $G = \langle(1,2,3,4,5,6)\rangle \le S_6$? This subgroup has order 6, which isn’t divisible by 4.